# display outputs in columns with awk

Tags: bash, awk

How do I display awk outputs in columns and not one append at the end of the previous one?

Comment: Probably the simplest thing to do is output tabs instead of newlines.  That is, instead of `print "solani."a[4]`, use `printf "%s\t", "solani."a[4]`  You'll end up with no trailing newline, but that's easy to fix.

Comment: yes that's it! updated my post (sorry)

Comment: ummm, you've added a second set of output values; did those come from the same source file, or a different source file; to put it another way ... how many sets of output do you expect to extract from a single file? and if you can have more than 1 set of data (to extract) from a file, please update your question to show what 2 sets of data would look like in the source file

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: not quite ... you've now stated the data come from a single file (ok, that's good to know), but it would still help to have an expanded sample of the raw data file to see what a couple sets of data look like (eg, what does the raw source data look like for the 2 output records: solani.1/76/dadantii.2053 and solani.2/39/dadantii.2054)

Comment: but you've already found an answer to my question just below haha

Comment: ok, if that works then great! :-); if you find the answer doesn't quite work right then it should be relatively easy to update given an updated input sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print` commands will terminate the output with a new line, hence the reason you're seeing each data item placed on a new line.

If you replace `print` with `printf` then each output will stay on the 'current' output line (ie, no new line character will be placed at the end of the output).

Keep in mind that you'll need to explicitly designate a field separator (eg, space, tab), eg:

```
printf "%s\t",$4 # will print field $4 followed by a tab
```

Then, when you want to terminate a line you can either run `print ""` or `printf "\n"` to add a new line character to the end of the output.

---

Assuming you want a tab as a field separator, you could combine your various `awk` commands into a single command like such:

```
$ awk '
/^Query= /     {split($0, a, ".") ; printf "solani.%s\t",a[4]}
/^$/           {q=1}
/Length/ && q  {split($0, b, "=") ; printf "%s\t",b[2]}
/./            {q=0}
/^>/           {split($0, c, ".") ; printf "dadantii.%s\n",c[4] }
' file

solani.1        76      dadantii.2053
```